Label align environment by a name not a number
I'm interested in giving an equation a name and not a number. E.g. I want equation to label the equation in the following align environment by "(Pythagoras)" instead of a number given by the align environment:
\begin{align}
a^2+b^2=c^2
\end{align}


Likely a duplicate: use \tag. I removed the $ characters, as this site doesn’t use MathJax.

The duplicate is about “a symbol”, but in the argument to \tag you can use pretty anything.
